# Sequelize.js joinTableAttributes Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have Users, Notifications, and a NotificationsUsers table (automatically generated by sequelize associations). I'm able to get all notifications to a user but I'd like to store a 'read' field (TRUE or FALSE value) in the association table. So far this has all been setup but I'm unable to pull the 'read' field from the association table.

My Code-

```
Usr.getNotifications({where: ['Notifications.createdAt >= ?', datetime], joinTableAttributes: ['read']}).success(function(notes) {
    defer.resolve(notes);
});
```

Which runs this query-

```
SELECT `Notifications`.*, `NotificationsUsers`.`read` as `NotificationsUser.read` FROM `Notifications`, `NotificationsUsers` WHERE `NotificationsUsers`.`UserId` = 1 AND `NotificationsUsers`.`NotificationId` = `Notifications`.`id` AND Notifications.createdAt >= '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

What I get back are just the Notifications table fields. An example of one of the results I get back-

```
{ dataValues: 
 { id: 7,
   type: 'Warranty',
   title: 'Warranty Request From Jim Bob',
   text: 'My sink is drippy. I don\'t like drippy sinks.' },
_previousDataValues: 
 { id: undefined,
   type: undefined,
   title: undefined,
   text: undefined },
__options: 
 { timestamps: true,
   createdAt: 'createdAt',
   updatedAt: 'updatedAt',
   deletedAt: 'deletedAt',
   instanceMethods: {},
   classMethods: {},
   validate: {},
   freezeTableName: false,
   underscored: false,
   syncOnAssociation: true,
   paranoid: false,
   whereCollection: [Object],
   schema: null,
   schemaDelimiter: '',
   language: 'en',
   defaultScope: null,
   scopes: null,
   hooks: [Object],
   omitNull: false,
   uniqueKeys: {},
   hasPrimaryKeys: false },
options: { isNewRecord: false, isDirty: false },
hasPrimaryKeys: false,
selectedValues: 
 { id: 7,
   type: 'Warranty',
   title: 'Warranty Request From Jim Bob',
   text: 'My sink is drippy. I don\'t like drippy sinks.',
   createdAt: Fri Sep 05 2014 11:18:40 GMT-0500 (CDT),
   updatedAt: Fri Sep 05 2014 11:18:40 GMT-0500 (CDT) },
__eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
isNewRecord: false,
NotificationsUser: 
 { dataValues: [Object],
   _previousDataValues: [Object],
   __options: [Object],
   options: [Object],
   hasPrimaryKeys: true,
   selectedValues: [Object],
   __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
   isNewRecord: false } }
```

Given the information any suggestions what I may be doing wrong? Why can't I I get the NotificationsUsers.read field?

Comment: The "read" field should be in "notes.NotificationUser.read"

Comment: Oh thanks! I did not notice that before.

Comment: On a side note: where is documented that you have to pass a raw query to the where of a generated get method instead of an object?